# One shot fql query - facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebooker, facebook-fql

```
$status = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT message,time FROM 
status WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=".$user.")");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($status);
echo "</pre>";
```

above query returns all statuses, i want only last 2 status messages. I have to make it with fql only. can anyone show me how its done??

Comment: Hint: Accept answers if you like them

Answer (score 1):

You can specify LIMIT 2 to return just two records.

```
$status = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT message,time FROM  
status WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=".$user.") LIMIT 2"); 

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($status); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Depending on what you want to achieve you may need to add an ORDER BY also.